# Types of Authentications

Tags: authentication

How many types of authentications are there in Sharepoint 2007 vs. 2010 vs. 2013.

In what scenarios do we use these types of authentication?

For each type, how does the logon form look like (Pictures would be very useful.)

Good answer will get 50 point for bounty.

Comment: Sorry, this is really a request for someone to write an essay for you and it just doesn't fit our QA format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go to great lengths in describing this. However technet have already beaten me to it for all 3... Damn them.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx

The little drop down to change the version of SharePoint for all 3 versions. This is the most comprehensive description that you will find.

Comment: no no, someone edit my questino's i asked no link, only pictre or descrptiion

Comment: It's far to much to write for these question and answer pages. Official links are the proper way of pointing users to answers. Your question calls for a more complex answer with many different scenarios and examples required. So even if someone wrote something for this page for you, it would still not include all the information you require. Sorry. This is why your post would of been edited.

Comment: Pictures would be useless as the login form can be styled to meet any branding requirements or your own can be created.

Comment: Agree - the question is way too vague. Judging from the comment by OP I don't think anyone is going to get those 50 bounty points even if we left it open :-(